# Setting HTML Content-Type charset to UTF-8 "destroys" SQL-requests

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, charset

On my website I use content that comes either of MySQL-databases or is directly written in the files. The database has the collation *utf8_general_ci*, the tables (of WordPress) use *utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci*.

If I don't set `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");`, the content that comes from the database is displayed correctly concerning umlauts (ä, ö, ü, etc.). But of the content that is directly written in the PHP-files the umlauts are displayed as cryptic signs.

Now if I set `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");`, it is the other way around.

How can I manage both ways of content to be displayed correct?

Answer (score 0):

If the content directly written in PHP files does not show up correctly, it means that you used an editor for your PHP source that doesn't save files in UTF-8. Is it a very old editor?

Look for the UTF-8 setting in your editor, open your PHP source files and save them again.

Comment: It is IntelliJ, and uploaded on a different server it is displayed correctly without setting the header-value.